# TYPEDEF PTR - size doesn't matter?

Tags: assembly, masm

I noticed using TYPEDEF to define PTR's with various data types doesn't seem to make any difference. For example, these three types seem to behave exactly the same when used to store and `mov` 32-bit addresses:

```
PTYPE TYPEDEF PTR 
PBYTE TYPEDEF PTR BYTE
PWORD TYPEDEF PTR WORD

.data 

arrayByte BYTE 10h,20h,30h

ptr_1 PTYPE arrayByte
ptr_2 PBYTE arrayByte
ptr_3 PWORD arrayByte

.code
main PROC

mov eax, ptr_1 
mov eax, ptr_2 
mov eax, ptr_3 

exit    
main ENDP
```

Is there any practical reason to specify a size other than it's more self-documenting?

Comment: didnt you just ask this question?  it tells the assembler which instruction to generate.  please read the intel documentation before asking this question again.

Comment: someone just asked this this week...

Comment: Please include the _exact MASM instruction_ in which these three directives appear to behave in the same way!

Comment: @old_timer I'm not sure what you mean by telling assembler which to generate - they seem to behave the same. I've Googled and looked in SO but couldn't find anything. Searched Intel documentation and nothing either. Could you please provide link to where this was asked?

Comment: @zx485 Edited example for more clarity

Comment: I'm not familiar with all those MASMese, but used that way, why should the `TYPEDEF` differ?

Comment: Look at the instruction set mov eax,a.  explain to me how the assembler is supposed to know if it is supposed to generate the read a byte and put it in eax, read a word and put it in eax, or read a dword and put it in eax instruction (machine code)?  It cant, you have to tell the assembler what instruction you want mov eax,a is at best one of three if not more possible different solutions.

Comment: @old_timer There is no compiler error saying that size operand is undefiend - the compiler knows because `eax` is 32-bits. There is no difference between these three types of PTR's in terms of what's moved to `eax`. And since the value can only be retrieved by using `[ ]` on the register, I don't see any difference.

Comment: While MASM does have some subtle type support (no other x86 Assembler have it, IIRC), it's so weak that I wouldn't really bother with it, and just write ordinary Intel syntax assembly (with all the "types" stuff left to the programmer do it manually). In your example I don't see how even typed assembler would emit something different, all the three movs are loading the same address of first element? Or maybe I don't even understand what MASM will do with that `ptr_1 PTYPE arrayByte`, is it alias, or is it storing `arrayByte` pointer into memory? Either way, forget about types in ASM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring and using pointer types has little use in MASM.  Types in MASM basically are just sizes and are only to used determine sizes of objects and operands and their compatibility size-wise.  If you generate a listing file while assembling your example code (after adding `.MODEL FLAT` and `END` directives so it assembles), you'll see that the type of `ptr1`, `ptr2` and `ptr3` are all DWORD:

```
Types:

                N a m e                  Size     Attr

PBYTE  . . . . . . . . . . . . .         00000004     Near32 PTR Byte
PTYPE  . . . . . . . . . . . . .         00000004     Near32 PTR
PWORD  . . . . . . . . . . . . .         00000004     Near32 PTR Word

...

Symbols:

                N a m e                 Type     Value    Attr

...
ptr_1  . . . . . . . . . . . . .        DWord    00000003 _DATA
ptr_2  . . . . . . . . . . . . .        DWord    00000007 _DATA
ptr_3  . . . . . . . . . . . . .        DWord    0000000B _DATA
```

The only thing I can see the about pointer types that might make them useful is the fact that they'll automatically change in size according to the memory model in force. So you if you assemble your example with `.MODEL SMALL` instead of `.MODEL FLAT` the types of `ptr1`, `ptr2` and `ptr3` become WORD instead of DWORD. Similarly if you delete the model directive and assemble it with the x64 version of MASM the types of those symbols becomes QWORD. However doing either of these things reveals that it's not as useful as it sounds, because the `MOV EAX, ...` instructions in your example code will then generate errors because of the operand size mismatch.  In practice a lot of other code would still need to be rewritten to adjust to the change in pointer size.

Another possibility is that the pointer types would somehow be used in macros to do something useful, but I can't really see what that would be. Even as documentation, using the pointer types is dubious, as other readers aren't going to know what `PBYTE` or `PTYPE` mean without searching through the code for their definition. I wouldn't recommend using them.

Comment: I guess self-documenting is the only real useful purpose then?