# What's the point of the pointer in MASM?

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

I am learning `Assembly Language For Intel-Based Computers`, and there is something that quite confuses me.

It is known that, we can use any General-Purpose Registers to address, like this:

```
.data
array1 byte 1,2,3,4
.code
mov esi,offset array1
mov al,[esi] ; al=1
mov al,[esi+1] ; al=2
mov al,[esi+2] ; al=3
mov al,[esi+3] ; al=4
```

The `[esi+idata]`(idata is the immediate data) is just like the pointer, strong and enough.

But the book tells me how to type define a pointer like this:

```
pbyte tpyedef ptr byte
.data
array1 byte 1,2,3,4
ptr1 pbyte array
.code
mov esi,ptr1
mov al,[esi] ; al=1
mov al,[esi+1] ; al=2
mov al,[esi+2] ; al=3
mov al,[esi+3] ; al=4
```

So what realy confuses me is that since the `array1` is a pointer to the data, what's the point of `ptr1`? The pointer also requires 4 bytes to store.

Isn't `mov esi,ptr1` equal to `mov esi,offset array1`?

Also, the book gives different types of the pointer like:

```
pbyte tpyedef ptr byte
pbyte tpyedef ptr word
pbyte tpyedef ptr dword
pbyte tpyedef ptr qword
```

Doesn't the pointer just point one byte in the memory? What's the difference? I have tried like this:

```
pt typedef ptr qword 
.data 
array byte 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
arrptr pt array
.code
mov esi,arrptr
mov eax,[esi]
```

And I get 04030201 in eax, a dword type, not a qword.

In summary, I wonder whether it is quite necessary for the pointer existence in MASM. Or is there something that the pointer can but `[esi+idata]` can't?

Comment: `ptr1` can be modified to move through data, while `array1` will always point to the beginning of data. It is a higher level abstraction so you don't have to explicitly use register indexing.

Comment: @m0skit0 Well, that is an usage I ignored, but I used to use register indexing(if more pointers need, I will `push` and `pop`).

Comment: `push` and `pop` only work on the stack.

Comment: @m0skit0 I mean I will push the pointer to the stack to store it before the register is used for another thing, and pop the pointer when I need to use it. It can also move through data.

Comment: `masm` has some silly high level features, this is one of them.

Comment: Using "typedef ptr" is essentially useless in MASM: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42162140/typedef-ptr-size-doesnt-matter/42167326

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Isn't mov esi,ptr1 equal to mov esi,offset array1?

Beware that `mov esi, ptr1` actually means `mov esi, DWORD PTR [ptr1]` and that's an important distinction.
It's an indirect level more than `mov esi, OFFSET array`.

Simply put - if `array` resides at, say, 0x1000 than `mov esi, OFFSET array` is just the readable version of `mov esi, 1000h` (the actual instruction executed).
While, if `ptr1` is at 0x1010, `mov esi, ptr1` is assembled into `mov esi, DWORD PTR [1010h]` - *Read the content of the DWORD at 0x1010 and store it into ESI*.

In order for the two instructions to have the same behaviour, the DWORD at 0x1010 must be 0x1000 (i.e. points to `array`).

It could, however, point to any other array as well.
In your example it is pretty much useless, not because you only have a single array but because the data is statically allocated - so you can always get its address with `OFFSET`.
Imagine you want to discard the first word of a string, a procedure can take a pointer as a parameter (that can be initialized with `OFFSET` if the data is statically allocated) and return a pointer to the first non-discarded word

```
+--- Original pointer, initialized with OFFSET
|
v
Hello world from SO!
      ^
      |
      +--- Pointer returned
```

You can save the result into a variable called, say, `ptr1`.
Now if you want to repeat the process, you need to use the value of `ptr1` as the input for the procedure.
No `OFFSET` will do since the value of the pointer cannot be deduced at assembler time.

---

> Doesn't the pointer just point one byte in the memory? What's the difference?

In general giving the assembler more information than needed comes handy to:

1. Document the code
2. Let it perform some initialization
3. Let it perform some check

Knowing that a variable is a pointer can help future readers.

`TYPEDEF PTR` [can be used to specify near and far pointers](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/artofasm/CH05/CH05-4.html#HEADING4-115), but that's irrelevant for protected mode as set up by any modern OS.
A far pointer is initialized differently from a near one.

Maybe MASM performs some check on the type of the pointer and the pointee? I doubt it, but I don't know admittedly.

As pointed out by [Michael Petch in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42530908/whats-the-point-of-the-pointer-in-masm/42532406?noredirect=1#comment72206328_42532406):

> MASM does in fact (unlike other assemblers) have rudimentary type checking on pointers to data that have been explicitly defined and then directly referenced.

---

> And I get 04030201 in eax, a dword type, not a qword.

The destination is 32-bit, so the source cannot be 64-bit.
If the programmer explicitly uses a size (e.g. with a register name or with `WORD PTR [...]`) then the implicit size is overridden.

---

> Is there something that the pointer can but `[esi+idata]` can't?

No, any high-level code feature is ultimately assembled into the ISA instructions, so by using them, you can emulate any high-level feature.

Note that some directive work at a meta level, like `.data`.
These cannot be emulated as they don't simply generate code.

Comment: I should have been more accurate. I mean I can use `[esi+idata]` with stack(store the pointer before register changed by other instructions) instead of the actual pointer and I think addressing by register is easier to some extent. Now I think just making it stored in the data segment maybe much more convenient. Thanks a lot for such detailed answer!

Comment: Also, in most calling conventions the returned pointer is in the register, isn't it? If I want to return in a pointer variable, I have to define one before calling the function.

Comment: @Kon stack is usually handy for small local temporaries; easy to allocate, easy to release upon return from function, great "locality" for caches (the caller modified stack by pushing the return address into it, so at least part of stack memory is hot in cache). About your question and MASM: MASM has several wanna-be-high-level directives and keywords, which I personally find useless and confusing. Maybe they can be handy for somebody using them daily and in larger project, but why would one write larger project in asm? I prefer simple raw way of asm, like `mov eax,offset array1 ; or [ptr1]`

Comment: MASM does in fact (unlike other assemblers) have rudimentary type checking on pointers to data that have been explicitly defined and then *directly* referenced. I personally think it is a useless feature.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelPetch, I'm adding your comment to my answer as I believe it is valuable. I'm leaving out the last sentence, though, even if I strongly agree with it.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I am still confused about "checking on pointers to data that have been explicitly defined and then directly referenced" . Would you like to give me an example? :)

Comment: @Kon : As an example. Try declaring (in MASM/TASM) a byte array this way `array1 db 1,2,3,4` . Then in your code try to directly move the first value with `mov ax, [array1]` . MASM/TASM should produce an error because it knows you defined `array1` as an array of bytes but the _AX_ register is 2-bytes. Now try it as `mov al, [array1]` and it should now work since the size of the array elements (a byte) and the size of _AL_ register match (both are a byte/8 bits). Besides MASM/TASM/JWASM there are very few assemblers that will even attempt this kind of rudimentary type checking.

Answer (score 1):

In ASM you NEVER actually ***need*** a typedef statement to develop an application. In practical terms they are little more than comment text  If you are using the FPU theres a few real internal formats to learn, but for standard 32bit ASM you really just need to know something's size, i.e. is it a BYTE a WORD or a DWORD. And of course, if you are interacting with libs that treat the MSB as a sign bit or you need to use signed values yourself then bear that in mind and use jge instead of jae etc. but it's not rocket science.

**The BIG question:** *Is this book an educational text that you are required to work through and therefore will be graded on how well you stick to its methods?*

- if YES, sorry mate, bite the bullet and start memorising that stuff.
- if NO I'd consider that maybe it was written by someone who thinks in C and is just translating their C-centric thoughts into ASM. (not a crime – probably a good guy to learn C from :)

You are obviously just learning but the questions you are asking are excellent.

> So what realy confuses me is that since the array1 is a pointer to the data, what's the point of ptr1?

For your example code there is none. As the DWORD at ptr1 is being initialised to OFFSET array1 then never changed.
However there *are* many times when you will want to maintain a global pointer to a list/array etc. If you are starting at the start of the array every time you enter that section of code, then as you point out, you can just use OFFSET ... easy. But if the nature of your task is such that you must remember where you were up to next time you go back to it, then you need to store that location somewhere; hence the pointer.

> The pointer also requires 4 bytes to store.

Sure, but don't get too hung up on pointer space, if a pointer is the right way to go for the job, 4 bytes is nothing. If it were me I would just declare it as:

```
.data

lpThisArray   dd  OFFSET array1
```

Because that's what it is, it's a DWORD. It's 32 iddy-biddy transistors that are individually either throwing a party or sleeping it off at any given instant. They neither know nor care if they are holding an array pointer, the cursor Y co-ord, your cousins cell number, or the word "TWIT". They've got lives to lead, they don't care about our issues... but it's OK! We're not flying blind here. We called it "lpThisArray" I'm pretty confident I'm not going to accidentally dial it and try to get cuz to pick me up some stuff on his way over after work. I'm just as clever at home too, I almost always remember not to stick the cutlery in the power outlets - It's amazing what you can do when you put your mind to it!

In 32bit land there is almost never any need to declare standard numeric/string/pointer etc. stuff using anything other than db, dw or dd, ( = BYTE, WORD or DWORD) because in the end that's what everything else boils down to anyway. FPU/SSE etc. aside everything is 8bits, 16bits or 32bits.

Of course the structure definitions and syntax are very handy, so if you're working with API structures (or cooking up big ones of your own) it makes sense to use them.

MyOfn OPENFILENAME <>

is dead easy to type anyway ;)

...just as long as you understand that:

```
.data?

csrPos  POINT  <>

.code

invoke GetCursorPos,OFFSET csrPos
mov ebx,csrPos.y
```

is identical in every way to:

```
.data?

csrX    dd  ?
csrY    dd  ?

.code

push OFFSET csrX
call GetCursorPos
mov ebx,csrY
```

They will compile to identical executable.

> Isn't mov esi,ptr1 equal to mov esi,offset array1?

Putting aside my personal dislike for the author's unnecessarily esoteric choice of data size declaration, the answer is yes ONLY when ptr1 is pointing to the start of the array. ptr1 defines a DWORD location that can hold any 32 bit value, but OFFSET array1 is a fixed value, it is the address of the first byte in the array.

Ok ... OFFSET for a beginner. Good point. Probably best to first think about the ".data" that's before it.

Unlike the declarations in higher level languages, that ".data" isn't some convenient human-centric heading under which you can list the numbers you want to play with. In ASM it defines the start of a physical section in the exe file that the system loader will map to a specific address in the process' virtual address space. From the time the program is compiled everything in there is defined as being at a specific, predetermined location. ( in theory they can be re-based but in practice they almost never are, and that has no bearing on this anyway ).

People used to higher level languages can be forgiven for assuming that when the program runs, it will reach a point where it finds this "OFFSET" guy, who promptly runs off and finds the array then reports back on its location. In fact OFFSET is a compiler directive that will cause the compiler to hard-code the actual memory address of the supplied label directly into the the program's opcodes. In this case array1 labels the location of the first byte in the array. That "OFFSET" defines exactly one and one only location that will never change for the lifetime of the executable. In this case you can think of ptr1 as a variable so it can hold any 32 bit value and that value can change 1000s of times a second.

DATA LABELS
That's handy for explaining the pointer point, but in actual fact it's inaccurate. "ptr1" is actually a label. It labels a specific location in the .data section and is also absolutely fixed for the life of the program. It is the 4 bytes at that location which hold the value of the pointer.

for example:

```
mov ptr1,12345

;( then later)

mov esi,OFFSET ptr1
mov eax,[esi]
; eax now holds 12345
```

The fact that OFFSET can accept ptr1 as an argument means it must be fixed. Data labels define locations just like any other label, the difference is only one of syntax convention in that data labels have *implied dereferencing* applied to them. "ptr1" just like every other label and indeed the result of OFFSET in that it compiles to a constant 32bit immediate value, but being a data label, when we code "ptr1" the MASM compiles "[ptr1]". This makes it easier for people to think of data labels as variables and use them as such, but it also does tend to obscure what is actually happening.

The other thing about data labels is that they have a size (not a *type*) attached to them. **This is the *feature* of MASM that many people (including myself on occasion;) tend to incorrectly refer to as a form of type checking.** Although at this point it becomes an almost philosophical discussion, MASM does famously keeps track of the size of everything that can actually be determined which saves the user from having to type "DWORD ptr" "BYTE ptr" or "WORD ptr" ad nauseum for virtually every instruction. This is not required since the compiler already knows what size almost everything is.

To my mind, this was very much implemented as a time saving/productivity increasing feature, however a by-product is that when the compiler attempts to process an instruction that involves two different size definitions, it doesn't know which one is correct and therefore doesn't know which opcode it should be generating so it can't continue. The only thing that irks me is that I feel we should be able to override this by explicitly declaring a SIZE ptr and not have to resort to the old chestnut of loading a register with the offset of the offending data label and dereferencing it thereby shedding the attached size declaration.

> Doesn't the pointer just point one byte in the memory?

Yes.. sort of. A pointer is just a number, it points to one *address* more than one *byte*, because with a 32 bit processor you can read or write either 1 2 or 4 bytes at a time to/from that address.

> ```
> pt typedef ptr qword 
> .data 
> array byte 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
> arrptr pt array
> .code
> mov esi,arrptr
> mov eax,[esi]
> ```

This is just a bit of confusion resulting from excess consumption of our would be Pulitzer winner's offerings....

In effect you have done this:

```
.data 
array  db 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
arrptr dd OFFSET array

.code
mov esi,arrptr
mov eax,[esi]
```

Which is a fairly roundabout way of doing this:

```
.data
array  db 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

.code
mov eax,OFFSET array
mov eax,[eax]
```

as you have loaded a value into eax whose source is a dereferenced pointer, any size definition that may have been attached to to the container that previously held the pointer is now long gone. For this mov instruction, the data size is being defined by the destination operand i.e. eax itself. As eax is a 32bit (4 byte) register, 4 bytes have been loaded into it.

> And I get 04030201 in eax, a dword type, not a qword

I implore you, should you ever figure out how to get a qword into eax, please do let me know the trick ;)

Comment: A THOUSAND THANKS. But I mean since we can use so many general registers to address like `[esi+idata]`, is it necessary to use pointer?(If I want to store the location somewhere, I can `push` the address in register and `pop`.) Also I say `not a qword` means I use a **qword** type pointer but get a **dword** data, which makes me confused  what the point of the definition of the type.

Comment: PART 1: a pointer is number that equals the address of something. you can store a pointer in a register. you can push/pop one to/from the stack, or you can store it in memory. your question seems to be "do i need to store it in an area of the .data section I have defined using a 'ptr' based typedef" in which case the answer is definately 'no'.

Comment: PART 2: types are a human construct. When your processor arrives at an address, it does not care what 'type' you think is there. for a 32bit CPU, it's going to read or write 1, 2 or 4 bytes as per the instruction, that's all. a QWORD is 8 bytes. a 32bit reg can only hold 4 bytes at a time. you can write funcs to do things with QWORDs, but whatever it is, they will only ever be doing it 4 bytes at a time. consider a POINT struct. a ptr to it is pointing to 2 DWORDs (=a QWORD). if there was another POINT struct following you could call it a RECT (DQWORD), but the ptr is still a 32 bit address.

Comment: So, what's the point of defining the pointer type? They are the same for the CPU.

Comment: IMHO very little, as I put in my answer, i would just use "lpThisArray   dd  OFFSET array1"

Comment: or actually I would probably put it in .data? and use 'lpThisArray dd ?' then initialize it later